# Rolling Difference for Intervals of Rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new at Python, and kinda stuck. I need to add a column to a dataframe containing the rolling difference of a column's value. However, I need this count to reset in intervals of 3. Best I could do was

```
df['Value'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
```

But I don't know how to reset the diff count. I've experimented with groupby, but with no results.

The table at hand looks like this

```
ID    Location   Year    Value

01       EU      2000    42.402
02       EU      2001    44.336
03       EU      2002    46.477
04       US      2000    0.456
06       US      2001    0.438
07       US      2002    0.437
```

The desired results should look like this:

```
ID    Location   Year    Value      RD

01       EU      2000    42.402    Null
02       EU      2001    44.336    1.934
03       EU      2002    46.477    2.141
04       US      2000    0.456     Null
06       US      2001    0.438    -0.124
07       US      2002    0.437     0.001
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by integer division by `3` for general solution with `arange` by length of `DataFrame`:

```
idx = np.arange(len(df)) // 3
#if default index
#idx = df.index // 3
s = df.groupby(idx)['Value'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], 'raw=False')
df['RD'] = s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   ID Location  Year   Value     RD
0   1       EU  2000  42.402    NaN
1   2       EU  2001  44.336  1.934
2   3       EU  2002  46.477  2.141
3   4       US  2000   0.456    NaN
4   6       US  2001   0.438 -0.018
5   7       US  2002   0.437 -0.001
```